# AES Rijndael and little/big endian?

Tags: networking, cryptography, rijndael, endianness

I am using the public domain reference implementation of AES Rijndael, commonly distributed under the name "rijndael-fst-3.0.zip". I plan to use this to encrypt network data, and I am wondering whether the results of encryption will be different on big/little endian architectures? In other words, can I encrypt a block of 16 bytes on a little endian machine and then decrypt that same block on big endian? And of course, the other way around as well.

If not, how should I go about swapping bytes?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards.

Comment: The trouble is, I am totally blind and so I am browsing the web with a screen reader (Jaws for Windows). That has trouble with certain parts of some pages, for instance I cannot seem to find out how to activate the "accept" option on an answer. Otherwise I'd gladly do so. The accept option only appears as normal text.

Comment: @user749473: I'll bet the stackoverflow site designers would love to make their more accessible to the blind. Maybe if you have time you could post a question/comment about your difficulties on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rijndael is oblivious to byte order; it just sees the string of bytes you feed it. You should do the byte swapping outside of it as you always would (with `ntohs` or whatever interface your platform has for that purpose).

Answer (score 4):

Byte order issues are relevant only in context of mapping multi-byte constructs to a sequence of bytes e.g. mapping a 4-byte sequence to a signed integer value is sensitive to byte order.

The [AES algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is byte centric and insensitive to endian issues.

Comment: I think you are wrong. The AES key schedule employs 32-bit words.